# Bash script - Running a command with value of variable doing nothing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I am having strange problem with my bash script. In my script if i am running a command using value of variable then command is doing nothing. Nothing means it is not giving any syntax error (I have checked the script debug logs)and if i just copy paste the same command from script to my shell prompt and it runs successfully. And if i set the value of variable  with fixed value inside my script then command from my script is running fine.Please note this variable is passed from one of tool automatically so i cannot set it with fixed value. Also if i am displaying the value of variable using echo command it shows me expected value.

Below is command in my script.

```
/opt/omni/bin/omniobjcopy -replist DEFRA_B6600_VEA-to-DEDUS_B6600_VEA-repl-obj-cpy-weekly -scheduled -session $SESSIONID
```

Below is command from script debug logs

```
omniobjcopy -replist DEFRA_B6600_VEA-to-DEDUS_B6600_VEA-repl-obj-cpy-weekly -scheduled -session 2018/02/06-9358
```

So i can see value of variable is as expected. As i said earlier if am setting the value of variable `SESSIONID` with value `2018/02/06-9358` inside my script then it running as expected.

Thanks in advance.

Below is set -x output .

[image]

Comment: How do you pass the variable from the tool to the script? If it's a variable in another script, you need to export it.

Comment: variable SESSIONID is getting passed from one of my tool to bash script. And if i am setting the variable with fixed value i.e. 2018/02/06-9358  just for testing command runs fine. I am setting variable SESSIONID=2018/02/06-9358 for testing.

Comment: Variable is set by tool and passed to script. And inside script if i am checking the value of variable it is as correct.

Comment: I believe it is passed as environment variable.

Comment: Sorry i cannot show the code from tool as whatever i am doing on tool is from GUI so i do not know much about the code behind the tool.

Comment: But while checking the variable value and it is correct.Same i can see inside the debug logs of script and also if i am displaying the value using echo command.

Comment: Variable has name i.e. SESSIONID and i am using same with command.

Comment: Never mind, I misread the question. The log shows that it's receiving the parameter correctly. I can't see any reason why the command would work differently from setting the variable by hand.

Comment: Please include `set -x` output. There's a lot of information that `echo` doesn't show.

Comment: On the line above the one you show, and before you first use the variable `SESSIONID` try inserting `SESSIONID=$(echo $SESSIONID)`

Comment: Hi Mark i tried inserting the variable but it did not help me.

Comment: @thatotherguy i am already using set -x in my script and it is showing value of variable correct.

Comment: Great. Can you copy-paste the `set -x` output and add it to the post, both for when it fails and when it works?

Comment: I have added the set -x output in my post. I have highlighted the value of variable in yellow which is correct. And you can see same is passed to command omniobjcopy. If i copy paste the same command on shell prompt it runs fine. But in script it give me error "no object to copy". One more thing if i am adding "&" in end of omniobjcopy command i.e. running the command in background then it runs fine even inside the script.